# Does the Managed Xamarin HttpClient Implementation support TLS 1.2?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, tls1.2

The official Xamarin documentation for App Transport Layer Security ([iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack?context=xamarin/cross-platform), [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?context=xamarin%2Fcross-platform&tabs=macos)) states that the managed *HttpClient implementation* does only support TLS 1.0. It strongly recommends updating Xamarin Apps to native HttpClient implementations to support TLS 1.2. Visual Studio states this as well:

[image]

However, the documentation is contradictory. When describing the managed *HttpClient implementation*, it states something like:

> It is not fully integrated with the OS (eg. limited to TLS 1.0).

The documentation later has contradicting statements like:

> Beginning with Xamarin.Android 8.3, HttpClientHandler defaults to Boring SSL ... It supports TLS 1.2+.

Furthermore, this [very helpful Xamarin blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/securing-web-requests-with-tls-1-2/) states that TLS 1.2 is indeed possible with the managed HttpClient implementation by choosing the *SSL/TLS option "native TLS 1.2"* (which is the default on iOS and cannot be changed on iOS).

Last, but not least, I tested the HttpClient of the current stable Xamarin version<sup>1</sup> against https://www.nist.gov, which only supports TLS 1.2. I verified that the server only accepts TLS 1.2 with:

```
openssl s_client -connect nist.gov:443 -no_tls1_2
```

If the managed HttpClient implementation really does only support TLS 1.0, I would expect that the following connection fails:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.nist.gov");
```

However, the connection succeeds with the following settings:

- iOS: HttpClient implementation *Managed*
- Android: HttpClient implementation *Managed (HttpClientHandler)* or *Default*, and SSL/TLS implementation *Native TLS 1.2*.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Is the Xamarin documentation outdated when stating that the managed HttpClient implementation does only support TLS 1.0?
2. Is my test against the https://www.nist.gov valid? Does it indeed show that the managed HttpClient implementation supports TLS 1.2? Or am I missing something?

---

<sup>1</sup> Visual Studio 7.5.2 (build 40), Xamarin.iOS 11.12.0.4, Xamarin.Android 8.3.3.2

Comment: The managed provider does NOT support TLS1.2... not sure about your testing, but you can review the code in the Mono repo and there is no 1.2 support.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, I believe this is where the two settings *SSL/TLS implementation* and the *HttpClient implementation* come into play. To my understand, the managed *HttpClient implementation* can use the *native SSL/TLS provider* on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, which support TLS 1.2. The managed TLS provider only supports TLS 1.0, but is not active in the current default Xamarin project settings. E.g. [this blogpost](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2016/Sep-30.html) talks about this, if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the "native" handler (Android or iOS) it is using the native APIs to implement the `HttpClientHandler` features and thus is "platform dependent" upon whether or not TLS1.2 would be supported, i.e. Android 5/API-21 does not natively support TLS1.2, most Android developers use a 3rd-party lib...

When you enabled "native SSL/TLS" is it using Google's BoringSSL (that is now included into your app bundle) and **not** the native platform APIs. Thus TLS1.2 is supported even with the "Managed" HttpClientHandler. This option allows the ".Net framework/Mono" to support the latest SSL/TLS on iOS & Android, such as .Net Sockets, WebClient, etc.. and of course HttpClient.

#### https://www.nist.gov Test:

```
Android Handler / Managed SSL    :  No exception
Managed Handler / Native SSL/TLS :  No exception
Android Handler / Native SSL/TLS :  No exception
Managed Handler / Managed SSL    :  Error: SecureChannelFailure
```

**SecureChannelFailure**:

```
MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) --->
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. --->
System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. --->
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
```